# names for accounting documents

Tags: word-choice, word-request, translation

I have an accounting system, and I'm looking for the correct terms for some documents...

As a seller, some of the documents that I can issue are "invoices" and "delivery notes".

But when I'm acting as a customer, what would be the correct name for an entity destined to keep track of the documents that a seller issues to me?

For invoices as was thinking of "proofs of purchase" (a direct translation of "comprobantes de compra" in spanish). And I have no idea what to call an entity for "delivery notes". Someone suggested me "delivery receipts" or "goods reception", but I'm not sure about those...

Comment: No idea what to call an entity for "delivery notes"? What's wrong with "delivery notes"? And I'm not convinced "invoices" is synonymous with "proofs of purchase", so why not call them "invoices"?

Comment: In an accounting context, the "things" (databases, record-keeping systems) that keep track of orders, invoices, deliveries, etc., are called ***ledgers***.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. The question is a little confusing—are documents also the product being exchanged? Why would there be any special entity that keeps track of documents? Also note that accounting has specialized terminology, and the way certain terms are used in accounting (e.g. *journal*, *discount*, *voucher*) differs from the way they are used by the general public. There may be further differences between countries, and between GAAP, IFRS, and other systems. In any case, it may not be advisable to ask non-experts for such translations.

Comment: In UK we use the term [**docket**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/docket) which is a document listing the contents of a delivery. In US it has a different meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica what I meant, is that if I issue an invoice, what would be the counterpart if such document is issued to me....would that be a "proof of purchase"? the same with delivery note. I need to keep track of those kind of documents and I want to store it with the proper name. I can't use invoice and delivery note respectively because those names are reserved for when I'm the one who issues them.

Comment: I think this is a matter of business practices and (possibly *local*) terminology. It's not directly related to "learning English"

Answer (score 1):

There is no "counterpart" The documents are called "invoices" "delivery notes" and receipts by both the customer and the seller.

Delivery note: A document sent by the seller with a product that lists the contents and prices.

Invoice: A document sent by the seller demanding payment.

Receipt: A document sent by the seller confirming that payment has been received.

Customers might send documents to the seller:

Order form: A request for products

Cover note: A short note that might be sent with payment .

So typically a customer sends an order to the seller, perhaps using an order form.  The seller sends the product to the customer, listing the contents in a delivery note.  The seller also sends an invoice to the customer. The customer sends payment to the seller (perhaps including a cover note). The seller sends a receipt to the customer. (If this is very different from the process in your country, please clarify the question)

Answer (score 0):

The word *Receipts* is nice choice and is commonly used to describe those documents that a seller would issue to you to acknowledge a purchase. *Receipt* is very general and will be understood to mean 'proof (paper or tangible object) given to you to indicate you paid x for y'.